# SET 2 Cron in AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I am trying to set 2 Cron on my AWS server with help of putty, But one Cron is not working.

1. First: `* * * * * php /var/www/html/api/update.php`
2. Second: `0 23 * * * php /var/www/html/api/sendmail.php`

First Cron runs properly, But the second Cron is not working.
Please tell me how we run more than one Cron?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an issue with **permission** and **ownership** of your `sendmail.php` file.

Check the ownership of file and then do changes accordingly in your `/etc/crontab` file :

```
0 23 * * * <owner of the file>  /var/www/html/api/sendmail.php
```

For example if the owner of file `/var/www/html/api/sendmail.php` is `root` then it should look something like this:

```
0 23 * * * root  php /var/www/html/api/sendmail.php
```